# Switch Between layouts on list to grid recyclerview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, gridview, android-recyclerview

How to switch layout when RecyclerView is List to Grid or vice versa.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing from a listview to a gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19076463/passing-from-a-listview-to-a-gridview)

Answer (score 7):

**build.gradle app level**

```
 compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
```

**ItemModel.java**

```
 public class ItemModel {

    private String name;
    private String imagePath;

    public ItemModel(){

    }

    public ItemModel(String name, String imagePath) {
        this.name = name;
        this.imagePath = imagePath;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getImagePath() {
        return imagePath;
    }

    public void setImagePath(String imagePath) {
        this.imagePath = imagePath;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.DividerItemDecoration;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    String imageUrl[] = Constant.image;
    String names[] = Constant.name;

    @BindView(R.id.my_recycler_view)
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        initView();
    }

    private void initView() {

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        List list = getList();
        mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(this, list);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
    }

    private List getList() {
        List list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < imageUrl.length; i++) {
            ItemModel model = new ItemModel();
            model.setName(names[i]);
            model.setImagePath(imageUrl[i]);
            list.add(model);
        }
        return list;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.switch_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                break;
            case R.id.switch_view:
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
                boolean isSwitched = mAdapter.toggleItemViewType();
                mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(isSwitched ? new LinearLayoutManager(this) : new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                break;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.sunil.switchlisttogridrecyclerview.MainActivity">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**RecyclerAdapter.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.List;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

/**
 * Created by sunil on 12/10/16.
 */

public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    private List itemModels;
    private Context context;
    private static final int LIST_ITEM = 0;
    private static final int GRID_ITEM = 1;
    boolean isSwitchView = true;

    public RecyclerAdapter(Context context, List itemModels) {
        this.itemModels = itemModels;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemModels.size();
    }


    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

        View itemView;
        if (i == LIST_ITEM){
             itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate( R.layout.item_layout, null);
        }else{
             itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_view_grid, null);
        }
        return new ItemViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ItemModel model = itemModels.get(position);
        initializeViews(model, holder, position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType (int position) {
        if (isSwitchView){
            return LIST_ITEM;
        }else{
            return GRID_ITEM;
        }
    }

    public boolean toggleItemViewType () {
        isSwitchView = !isSwitchView;
        return isSwitchView;
    }



    private void initializeViews(ItemModel model, final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        String imageUrl = model.getImagePath();
        if (imageUrl != null && !imageUrl.isEmpty()){
            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(imageUrl)
                    .into(((ItemViewHolder)holder).imageView);

        }
        ((ItemViewHolder)holder).name.setText(model.getName());
    }

    public static class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        @BindView(R.id.name)
        TextView name;
        @BindView(R.id.imageView)
        ImageView imageView;

        public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

**item_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp">
   <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:text="name"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/imageView"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**item_layout_grid.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="0dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp" />

      <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:text="name"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"/>

   </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Screenshot of application with a grid list of items]
[image: Screenshot of application with a list of items]

Comment: Why are you calling `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu` when you've selected the switch view menu item?